# opauth implementation and and issue with session id

Tags: php, session, opauth

I am trying to implement [opAuth login](https://github.com/opauth/opauth). php 5.4.45. When I start my php page, I call

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();
```

After this, if I print `session_id()`, it will print say "fsdfoasdiuhf736jf732938f92" (i)

Now I click on facebook login by OpAuth. All is fine, I get the user data correctly, but on the callback page, the session Id is different. ie, if I print session_id(), it will print an id different than (i)

The trouble is, now if I save the username as $_SESSION['user'] and redirect to home page, on the homepage, it is back to the original session id (i) again. and username is not set there.

Everypage that is involved, i check before starting a session. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

I think I have a clue to what may be happening. When I call the login url, there is the original session id. I pass the callback url to this function. When facebook authorizes the login and redirects to the callback url, May be php is looking at this as a request from facebook? which means it is a new session so it creates a new session? not the same as the one the user was on? And then when php redirects to the original page, the original session is back on? Does this make sense? If so, how can I keep the sessions the same?

Comment: I'm guessing OpAuth is regenerating the session ID since there is a permission elevation going on.. Perhaps, using `session_id('setnewsidreceivedfromOauth')` would solve it..

Comment: but then, when I go back to home page, how is it going back to the original session id? is that possible? They use 'session' as the default callback_transport. I even changed this to 'post' and still the same thing happens.

Comment: On deeper inspection of OpAuth, it only starts a new session if the callback is set to a session. It has to be something else then. You could potentially replace line 229 `opauth.php` with the line of code you have. Not sure if thats "works as designed" though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue. The actual page with the login button was a non www page, and the login button had a www url on it. So when the callback url is formed, it defaults to a www url. This is different from the non www url so a new session is formed. I changed all to non www url and it is working as expected.